# Laravel 4: How to display a message without redirecting?

Tags: php, html, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

**This is the situation:**

In my Laravel 4 app, after validating, it redirect to the same page displaying a succesfull message.

It works fine. The problem is that the page is quite heavy and so the redirecting process it takes up to 3 seconds.

What i would like to do, is to display a message without redirecting.
In order to save the time that takes to load the page again, and display the message instantly.

**This is the code:**

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message','<b>Congratulations! You have succesfully sent the email');
```

**This is the question:**

It is possible to obtain the same result, that is to display a succesfull message, without redirect to the same page?
If yes, how can this be done?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you could use a xajax function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you only can do it with AJAX and Javascript, send the data by ajax and show the info with javascript

Comment: Could you make an example?

Answer (score 2):

The common method is doing validating by `AJAX`.

And Show the success or fail message by different response.

You can use native javascript `XmlHttpRequest` Object or jQuery `$.ajax` Function ... and so on to do AJAX.

you can refer below resource:

javascript `XmlHttpRequest` Object:
http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.html

jQuery `$.ajax` Function:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Can i ask a delucidation? Right now in my controller i do 3 things: 1- display succesfull message 2- insert data in the database 3- send the email. The real validation is made client side with Jquery (but i made also a second validation on server side).
You mean to do all the tasks by AJAX, or just display the message by AJAX? What do you think if i display a message using Jquery when the user click on the SUBMIT button (if jquery validation success)? Thank you!

Comment: if `2 & 3` is also your validation process, do all in ajax. I usually do: 1. load page by Laravel. 2. click submit then send ajax request to other function which handle ajax in controller 3.controller send response, something like JSON: {"status":1} 4. according to ajax response `status` put different message on screen

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Chen-Tsu Lin answer with a full generic example, applicable in Laravel:

First off, your code should work without any javascript so you need to expand on what you already have.

Make a route listen to ajax request (post or get whichever suits you better):

```
Route::post('helpers/ajax',
array('as' => 'ajax',  'uses' => 'App\Controllers\AjaxController@someMethod')
);
```

Using jQuery, you will stop default function of form submission and send it to your ajax uri

```
$('#yourSubmitButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // the form will not be submitted
    //do whatever necessary to collect the data, or just serialize the form
    var formdata = $('#yourForm').serialize();
    //perhaps validate the data, if you need, and then send by ajax
    $.ajax({
    url:'helpers/ajax',
    type:'POST', //or GET if you wish as long as its consistent with the route
    data: formdata,
    dataType:'json', //this is for the data you will receive from the controller
    cache:false,
    success:function(data){
     //show the "mail send message and whatnot
    },
    error:function(jxhr){
     //handle errors
    } })
    })
```

What's missing is the method on your controller, to receive the post data, validate, process and echo the request (most probably a json_encoded array).

Anything more is specific to your implementation.